What is an efficient method to manually create image descriptions?
I want to add descriptions to a few thousand images and I'm looking for an efficient way to do this.  Ideally I'd like something on Android where I see the image, I can speak the description, it gets transcribed to text and stored in some way with the image.  Then I click next/OK, see the next image and repeat.
Has anyone done something similar or have an idea of how they would do it?

Take a look on amazon sagemaker ground truth
